# expo a modal overlay which is displayed alone when I open my app

Tags: react-native, expo

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG4jB.png)

it appears every time I do a new installation of the app, I don't understand why this appears, I searched and I don't know what package it comes from, I have the impression that it's is an ad, because when the app is not connected to the internet it is not displayed!

I tried to look for where this came from but I couldn't find any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this `template` before. Does your project use `OneSignal`? It is a third party Free Push Notification Service. The functionality you see is OneSignals `InApp notifications` which are configured to display when the user opens the application.